# Edge Rails doesn't list plugin/gem generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, cucumber, generator

I recently created a project skeleton with Edge Rails and installed `rspec`, `rspec-rails` and `cucumber` as plugins (git submodules). If I run:

```
$ script/generate
```

all I get is a list of built-in generators. The ones from the plugins don't show up. I installed the same plugins as gems and got the same result. Does anyone know why this is happening and/or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best best is probably to create an issue on the Rails ticket system - http://rails.lighthouseapp.com. It will get seen by the right people there.